# php sql for use 10 last child

Tags: php, mysql

`"SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10"` It is my code (MYSQL Code)

Output:

`Item 22`,`Item 21`,`Item 20`,`Item 19`,`Item 18`,`Item 17`,`Item 16`,`Item 15`,`Item 14`,`Item 13`

I don't like this

I want this output :

!! I can't use `"ORDER BY id ASC"` !!

`Item 13`,`Item 14`,`Item 15`,`Item 16`,`Item 17`,`Item 18`,`Item 19`,`Item 20`,`Item 21`,`Item 22`

Comment: Why can't you use `ORDER BY id ASC`?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isaace figured out what you were after, but i think it can be expressed more succinctly...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT * 
         FROM `table` 
        ORDER 
           BY id DESC 
        LIMIT 10
     ) x
 ORDER
    BY id;
```

Comment: is my answer incorrect?

Comment: @isaace No - but I think it will be slower on larger data sets.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT a.* FROM table  a
JOIN (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) 
b on b.id = a.id     
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) A1 ORDER BY id ASC

Comment: Hm, looks familiar.